# mRemoteNG: How can I set a password on a connection file?

Tags: remote-desktop

Is it possible to set a password or pincode on the connectionfile as a whole?

Obviously I have secured the file through Windows security, but additionally I would really like to prevent other people accessing my connectionfile if my main Windows domain account is compromised.

Version of mRemoteNG in use: 1.74.6023.15437

Answer (score 8):

Eventually I figured it out:

1. Open a connection file in mRemoteNG you want to password protect;
2. Click the Connections node;
3. In the Config panel you will see a property "Password protected" with its default value "No";
4. Toggle this property to "Yes" and mRemoteNG will query for a password;
5. Choose a password;
6. Save the connection file.

Screenshot:
[image: mRemoteNG-password-protect.png]

Comment: Dear God, what an awful UI pattern.